# Is secondary follicle or Graafian follicle arrested in the second metaphase of oogenesis?

Tags: homework, oogenesis

My note about which I am not sure:

> Secondary oocyte is arrested in the metaphase II monthly after puberty until fertilization with sperm.

The following picture also satisfies my sentence: [image].

So you can see that the secondary oocyte that is arrested seems to be Graafian.

I know that Graafian develops during the second week.
I know that the secondary follicle is developing two days before [ovulation](http://www.embryology.ch/anglais/dbefruchtung/eisprung02.html).
It seems that the development of the secondary follicle ends and the formation of Graafian follicle occurs just before ovulation. 
My lecture material suggests that Graafian follicle is arrested in metaphase II, since Graafian follicle is ovulated once in a month and waits sperm in tuba uterina infundibulum:

[image]

The answer to my question is not also clear from [my previous thread](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/954/does-human-female-meiosis-ii-occur-after-fertilization-with-sperm):

> An oocyte completes meiosis I as its follicle matures (during ovulation) resulting in a secondary oocyte and the FIRST polar body. After ovulation, each oocyte continues to metaphase of meiosis II.

**Which follicle is arrested in the metaphase II of oogenesis?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graafian follicle.

The secondary oocyte and thus Graafian follicle are arrested in the second metaphase of oogenesis.
After this the corpus luteum develops from the follicle during the luteal phase of the menstrual cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Three follicular stages are recognised,
1) Primary/Preantral Follicles (with primary oocyte inside)
2) Secondary/Antral Follicles (with primary oocyte inside)
3) Pre Ovulatory Follicles (with secondary oocyte inside)

Pre ovulatory Follicles are formed ~36 hrs before ovulation at time of LH surge. This coincides with completion of Meiosis I and formation of the secondary oocyte. The secondary oocyte immediately enters Meosis II.

Appx. 3 hrs before ovulation, the Pre ovulatory Follicle (with the secondary oocyte inside) is arrested in the metaphase of Meiosis II and is extruded out of the ovary - a process called as Ovulation.

It comes to rest in the ampulla of the fallopian tube and here it is fertilised. As the sperm pronucleus is released into the cytoplasm, the Secondary Oocyte (now called the ovum) completes Meiosis II and releases the second polar body.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Akshay. It would be great if you can cite a reference.